# how to deduce the slide ppt position of a shape from the screen position of the mouse

Tags: vb.net, vba, vsto, powerpoint

I'm using VB to implement a custom task pane for Powerpoint.
I would like to display an image shape on the active powerpoint slide at the position of the mouse.
I know screen position of the mouse by using " System.windows.froms.control.MousePosition.Y " .. So now it would be great to transform it into slide ppt position and fill the property "shape.top".

I tried the function "screentoclient" but it doesn't work. What is the unit of shape.top on ppt slide? what is the unit of mouse's screen coordinates?

It is important that the solution works for any size of the screen ...

Comment: If you're using System.anything, you should probably remove the VBA tag from the post.  But moving on ... the units PPT exposes to automation are Points, 72 points to the inch. PowerPoint's PointsToScreenPixelsX and PointsToScreenPixelsY may be useful, though more for normal mode than screenshow mode.  Knowing the screen resolution/aspect ratio and the presentation object's PageSetup.SlideHeight and .SlideWidth and a bit of ratio calculation should get you there for screen coordinates.

Comment: And to make that a bit clearer, you'd need to do this backwards: get the cursor position on screen, then iterate through the shapes on the slide to find one (or possibly more) whose position (in points converted to screen pixels) puts it under the cursor.

Comment: Thanks Steve for your message. sorry for the delay. I didn't quite understand. I just have one shape to display on the active powerpoint slide at the position of the mouse.

Comment: If i lock the powerpoint's window size, i can manage (by resolving an equation) to find the value of Myshape.top that corresponds to any screen position of the mouse. So i can display the shape at the right position.

But if the user change the size of the window, it doesn't work anymore. I was thinking that it was just a matter of translation because i can find the new position of the slide by using "documentwindow.PointsToScreenPixelsY(0)" .... but not! ... the slide's coordinates system has completely changed ... maybe due to the resolution ...

Answer (score 3):

Have a go with this (VBA ... you'll need to translate to .NET)

```
Sub Test()

    Dim oSh1 As Shape
    Dim oSh2 As Shape

    ' Assuming nothing on the slide but two rectangles
    ' The first with its left edge just touching the left of the slide
    ' The second with its RIGHT edge just touching the right of the slide:

    Set oSh1 = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1)
    Set oSh2 = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(2)

    MsgBox "Upperleft = " & vbCrLf _
        & oSh1.Left & " / " & ActivePresentation.Windows(1).PointsToScreenPixelsX(oSh1.Left) & vbCrLf _
        & oSh2.Left + oSh2.Width & " / " & ActivePresentation.Windows(1).PointsToScreenPixelsX(oSh2.Left + oSh2.Width)

    ' Or just working directly with the slide dimensions:
    MsgBox "Upperleft = " & vbCrLf _
        & 0 & " / " & ActivePresentation.Windows(1).PointsToScreenPixelsX(0) & vbCrLf _
        & ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth & " / " & ActivePresentation.Windows(1).PointsToScreenPixelsX(ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth)

    ' Both give exactly the same results

End Sub
```